# KDE Connect no longer able to send SMS?

Tags: 19.04, kde-connect, kde-apps

I have KDE Connect on Ubuntu 19.04 and the option to reply to SMS has seemingly disappeared. I have it enabled on my device, but the option all together is gone from the KDE Connect app. Looks like maybe they removed it in the 08/19/19 update? 1.3.4-0ubuntu1

Comment: HI I was able to send SMS via KDE connect until I installed / upgraded to 19.10.  After 19.10 it stopped working.  The SMS dialog comes up and I cna fill-in a message.  Nothing happns when I press Send.  The workaround is to copy my text and paste it into the phone by hand.  The SMS feature is my #1 use-case for KDE Connect.